# How do you retrieve a document from a collection by its id in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to retrieve a single document by its ID (which I have access to).
I know how to send a query in firestore, that is not exactly what I'm needing. 
I need to know how to filter my listening request as described.

This is what I've tried:

this is my export (where you listen in firestore with reactJS)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const encounters = state.firestore.data.encounters;
    let encounter = encounters ? encounters[id] : null;
    return{
        encounterId: id,
        encounter: encounter,
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }};
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect((props) => {
            return [{collection: 'encounters', where: [['encounterId', '==', props.encounterId]]}]
        }
    )
)(Encounter);
```

I've done something very similar to this with good results using:

```
    firestoreConnect((props) => {
        return [{collection: 'characters', where: [['userId', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid]]}]
        }
    ),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchtoProps)
)(CharacterDetails);
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What*s not working exactly?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer My collection is coming back without any data in it. It's acting like I'm not listening to the right collection.

Comment: Did you check if your `props.encounterId` keeps the right value?